# Parsing a value using regular expression in java

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to read a line and parse a value using regular expression in java. The line that contains the value looks something like this,

```
...... TESTYY912345 .......
...... TESTXX967890 ........
```

Basically, it contains 4 letters, then any two ASCII values followed by numeric 9 then (any) digits. And, i want to get the value, 912345 and 967890.

This is what I have so far in regular expression,

...    TEST[\x00-\xff]{2}[9]{1} ...

But, this skips the 9 and parse 12345 and 67890. (I want to include 9 as well).

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are pretty close. Capture the entire group `(9\\d*)` after matching `TEST\\p{ASCII}{2}`. This way, you'll capture the `9` and the following digits:

```
String s  = "...... TESTYY912345 ......";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("TEST\\p{ASCII}{2}(9\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1)); // 912345
}
```

Answer (score 2):

See [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12396832/parsing-a-value-using-regular-expression-in-java#comment16657899_12396832) for a working expression, `"TEST.{2}(9\\d*)"`.

```
final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("TEST.{2}(9\\d*)");
for (final String str : Arrays.asList("...... TESTYY912345 .......",
         "...... TESTXX967890 ........")) {
  final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
  if (matcher.find()) {
    final int value = Integer.valueOf(matcher.group(1));
    System.out.println(value);
  }
}
```

See the result on [ideone](http://ideone.com/ZyycX):

> 912345
>
> 967890

This will match any two characters (except a [line terminator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#lt)) for what is `XX` and `YY` in your example, and will take *any* digits after the `9`.